# Aggregate and Calculate Percentiles in Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, aggregate, dax, percentile

Firstly thank you for any help anyone can provide on this one.

I need to be able to

1. Calculate Percentiles for bed-days at the top-level grouped by months and quarters.
2. Be able to slice on other fields and have the percentiles recalculated.

To allow for a tabulated output akin to what is produced in a box plot.
(other summary metrics will be going alongside)

Sample Data

[image: Bed Days Data]

This should return a total of bed days to be fed into the percentile for 12 days on 01/04/2021 and 19 days for 02/04/2021 or 6 and 11 days if I sliced on cardiology.

[image: Example Output]

Thanks again.
Joe

Comment: To get the number of days use this simple measure:

    BedDays = calculate(SUM(Table[BedDays]))
    MedinaBedDays = calculate(MEDIAN(Table[BedDays]))

Comment: Thanks for your reply, In your example i think the median value returned for the month would be 3.5 as the days aren't being aggregated up prior to going into the median function, as opposed to the 15.5 expected. It's even more noticeable in my data as i have a large number of 0's

Comment: I should say the thing which it will always be being grouped by is the day. The way i'd have previously tackled in excel would've been pivoting up to get the total beddays (with slicers attached) by day and then running a percentile if function, across the months.